# Heap size parameter xmx is overriden

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I'm running jre 6u24 on Fedora (Linux xxx 2.6.33.7.2-rt30 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Mar 21 00:50:23 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux).

It's an embedded system and other (business critical) applications are using it, so I am forced to limit the heap space to 300mb. Unfortunately, the jvm Xmx and Xms options don't have any effect and thus seem to be overriden. The jvm still uses about 400mb of virtual memory.

Does anybody know what's causing the override? Is there a default minimum heap size in jre 6u24? Is there another way to limit the heap space to 300mb?

TIA

James

Answer (score 1):

The heap settings should work, however note that this limits only the Java heap size, and does not include the memory used by the JVM itself, native libraries, etc. - everything outside the Java heap. It sounds reasonable that it might take up an extra 100m for everything else (of virtual memory, which is not necessarily really used - not physical memory).